# How to space out a barcode's digits using ZPL?

Tags: printing, zpl, barcode-printing, zpl-ii

I'm attempting to space out the displayed digits when creating a barcode, so instead of displaying a long string like `0000275920017` it would look something like `00   0   0 2759  20017`.

My current code

```
^BY4,2.0,200^FT80,1155^BCN,,Y,Y,N,U
^FD>;008717100000012283^FS
```

Any ideas or thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any mechanism in ZPL to add spaces to the human readable. I'd turn off human readable for your bar code and add another text field with the spacing that you want.

Comment: That's what I feared the answer might be.  I noticed that certain barcodes have the spacing built into them in the manual, but don't actually look that way on the labels I'm making.  I don't believe it is something that is within my control at any rate.  Thank you.